# Cómo puedo incluir librería beecrypt en un proyecto en C

Tags: c

Tengo un archivo .lib (librería) y quiero usarla en un proyecto de C.

Para ser más especifica estoy intentando instalar beecrypt que es una librería de encriptación. Algo como:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "beecrypt.lib"
```

Comment: Esa libreria es la q esta en sourceforge?? pq si es asi, esta en c++. No se como va a reaccionar a tu programa en C. Igual para incluirla, necesitarias incluir el header.

Comment: así como está en el código de propones  la librería debería estar en el mismo directorio que  la aplicación. Tu pregunta es como hacer que esté disponible siempre? es decir para todos los futuros programas que desarrolles?

Answer (score 1):

> Tengo un archivo .lib (librería) y quiero usarla en un proyecto de C.

Loas archivos `.lib` son archivos de librería de [elnazado estático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlace_est%C3%A1tico) y no están pensados para ser incluidos (mediante la instrucción de [preprocesador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocesador_de_C) `#include`). Este tipo de librerías ya han sido compiladas por el proveedor de la librería y para darles uso se necesita incluir sus cabeceras y [enlazar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlazador) con la librería precompilada.

Así que tienes dos cosas que hacer:

## 1) Incluir [cabeceras](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_de_cabecera).

Los archivos de cabecera de la librería (`.h` es la extensión por defecto en C) deben estar en una ruta disponible para que el compilador acceda a ellos. El compilador busca los archivos de cabecera en tres rutas:

- Ruta en que se encuentra el archivo a compilar.
- Ruta(s) de cabeceras de sistema.
- Ruta(s) configurada(s) en la lista de inclusiones.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tienes la siguiente configuración:

- `main.cpp` en `C:\programacion\proyecto1\main.cpp`
- Librerías del compilador C en: `C:\Program Files\c_compiler\lib\C11`
- Ruta de inclusión(es) en: `C:\programacion\3rd_party\`

Supongamos también el siguiente contenido de `main.cpp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // Cabecera de sistema
#include <stdlib.h>   // Cabecera de sistema
#include "my_utils.h" // Cabecera propia
#include "beecrypt.h" // Cabecera de una libreria

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Las inclusiones cuyo nombre de archivo está entre paréntesis angulares (`<` y `>`) se buscan en primer lugar en las rutas de cabeceras de sistema, así que `stdio.h` y `stdlib.h` serán buscadas en<sup>1</sup>:

1. Ruta del archivo a compilar: `C:\programacion\proyecto1\`
2. Ruta de sistema: `C:\Program Files\c_compiler\lib\C11`
3. Ruta de inclusiones: `C:\programacion\3rd_party\`

Mientras que `my_utils.h` y `beecrypt.h` serán buscadas en:

1. Ruta del archivo a compilar: `C:\programacion\proyecto1\`
2. Ruta de inclusiones: `C:\programacion\3rd_party\`

En ambos casos dejará de buscar en el momento en que encuentre el archivo de cabecera.

#### ¿Cómo configuro estas rutas?

Depende del IDE que estés usando (cosa que no has mencionado en tu pregunta), las rutas de las cabeceras de sistema deberían estar ya configuradas tras instalar el IDE o el compilador que estés usando así que éstas no deberían preocuparte. En cuanto a las demás rutas de inclusiones deben configurarse en el IDE (cada uno de ellos lo hará de una manera diferente) o si estás compilando desde línea de comandos, uno de los parámetros del compilador será la(s) ruta(s) de inclusión(es).

## 2) Especificar ruta de librerías estáticas.

Esto también depende del IDE que estés usando y de si compilas mediante IDE o desde línea de comandos, las rutas de librerías dinámicas deben configurarse en el IDE (cada uno de ellos lo hará de una manera diferente) o si estás compilando desde línea de comandos, uno de los parámetros del compilador será la(s) ruta(s) donde se encuentran los archivos para enlazar.

---

<sup>1</sup>El orden de búsqueda depende de la implementación del compilador, puede ser diferente en diferentes compiladores.

Comment: Estoy usando linux y compilo en comando, estoy usando C9.io que es en linea

Comment: @AnaGonzalez ¿Qué compilador estás usando en línea de comandos?

Comment: gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)   GNU

Comment: Entonces posiblemente debas usar un comando parecido a `gcc main.cpp -I C:\programacion\3rd_party\ -L C:\carpeta\donde\esten\los\archivos\lib`. Puedes consultar las opciones de línea de comandos [aquí](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html).

Comment: Por otro lado, creo que no es habitual la extensión `.lib` en sistemas Linux, ¿generalmente no son `.o`?

Comment: La verdad no sabría decirte, es la primera vez que uso una librería de este modo, es para la escuela, ocupo cualquier librería de encriptación

Answer (score 0):

Depende que libreria.

Si es una estandar, es probable que no sea necesario, porque vienen instaladas con el Compilador. Si es otro tipo, bueno. La mayoria de las librerias yo las descargo desde el DevC++ con el sistema de actualizaciones. Te hace todo el trabajo.

Comment: La verdad no sabría decirte, es la de beecrypt.lib